# Updating Member Status Options?

Tags: administration, campaign-member

Hello Stack Exchange!

I'm really struggling to find the option to create new labels for the Campaign Member Status picklist.

[image]

We'd like them to reflect RSVPs for events as this is the primary use for our campaigns.

When I go to the picklists in the Campaign Object I can't see the right fields to update.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this function (configuring the status values on a campaign) is available only in Classic. Access it by clicking Advanced Setup on the Campaign record page.

[image]

The Status picklist in the Campaign object doesn't define these values. They're stored in separate CampaignMemberStatus records, and cannot be defaulted globally (see this [very old Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br5dAAC)).

I've previously used [AAKonsult's free app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005utCcEAI) to remedy this issue by defaulting the status values based on the Campaign Type.

Comment: FYI not free anymore but not end of the world either, 20 AUD / org / month.